# Flutter - TextFormField textAlign doesn't apply the alignment to the error message

Tags: flutter

How can I align the error message to be centered as is the input text?

This is the code:

```
TextFormField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'The name cannot be empty.';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Comment: It seems that's not possible as of today. There's an open issue for it : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21343